# Postgresql left join and where != clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

here is a little SQL schema to reproduce my problem.

```
begin;

drop table if EXISTS book CASCADE ;
drop table if EXISTS author CASCADE ;
drop table if EXISTS book_author_asso CASCADE ;

create table book (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100)
);

create table author (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(100)
);

create table book_author_asso (
    book_id integer references book(id),
    author_id integer references author(id)
);

insert into book (name) values ('toto'), ('toto2');
insert into author (name) values ('robin1'), ('robin2');
insert into book_author_asso (book_id, author_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2);

commit;
```

I need to find books where author is not id 1.

```
=> select * from book b left JOIN book_author_asso a on a.book_id=b.id where a.author_id != 1;
 id | name | book_id | author_id 
----+------+---------+-----------
  1 | toto |       1 |         2
(1 row)

=> select * from book b left join book_author_asso a on a.book_id=b.id where a.author_id is null or a.author_id != 1;
 id | name  | book_id | author_id 
----+-------+---------+-----------
  1 | toto  |       1 |         2
  2 | toto2 |         |          
(2 rows)

=> select * from book b left JOIN book_author_asso a on a.book_id=b.id and a.author_id != 1;
 id | name  | book_id | author_id 
----+-------+---------+-----------
  1 | toto  |       1 |         2
  2 | toto2 |         |          
(2 rows)
```

Could someone explain me why the first query do not return the line with the id 2 ?

Comment: A row passes `where` clause if `where` condition evaluates to `true` on it. `null` is neither equal no not equal to anything which leads `a.author_id != 1` to be `null` (not equal to `true`) and doesn't allow the second row to be in the result set.

Comment: Regarding your task: 1) books that has *other* authors except id = 1 (then your second query should answer this) or 2) books that *do not have* author with id = 1. Then you need to use `not exists`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone explain me why the first query do not return the line with the id 2 ?

Because of predicate `where a.author_id != 1`. When a row has no author, `author_id` is `null`, which does not satisfy the inequality predicate - so the rows are filtered out.

In Postgres, we have null-safe equality operator `IS DISTINCT FROM`:

```
select * from book b 
left join book_author_asso a on a.book_id = b.id
where a.author_id is distinct from 1;
```

Conceptually this implements the same check as in your second query:

```
where a.author_id is null or a.author_id != 1
```

Comment: Thx for this quick explanation and the one operator solution.